# Aure app Service with custom domain DNS configuration

Tags: azure, dns, azure-web-app-service

I currently have a domain registered at Ionos with a web hosting package (email, .net hosting).

I plan to move the hosting to Azure App Service. I would like to continue using the email from Ionos and to continue to handle the domain from Ionos. So I only want my domain to target my Azure App Service instead of the Ionos hosting.

In my Azure App Servce, I added my custom domain by adding the following lines in my DNS (managed in Ionos) :

- Name, Type, Value
- www, CNAM, myapp.azurewebsite.com
- asuid.www, TXT, my verification id

It looks like this is the only thing to configure. However, my Azure app is still not in used. I tried to stop my App Service, the website is still responding. I tried to remove the folder on my Ionos hosting folder and it stop working. So it looks like the DNS of my website still target Ionos host instead of Azure App Service.

Am I missing something?

Thank you very much for your help! :)

Dorian

Comment: DNS changes can take some time to propogate, I typically have to wait a few hours to see changes.

Comment: Also, here's a useful tool to examine the DNS records for your domain: https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/dig/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was from the Ionos portail to configure the DNS.
In my case I had to do the following :

- Redirect my naked domain to the www subdomain through the Ionos redirection feature
- Crete the new DNS entry (CNAME and TXT) to link my www subdmain to my new host
- Regenerate a new SSL certificate (due to an error on Ionos side)

The Ionos portal is often not up to date, and sometimes it just displays wrong information.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this video tutorial to learn.

[How to Transfer a Domain Name to Azure](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EraHoPwZ7MQ)

More details can refer to this article, [Tutorial: Map an existing custom DNS name to Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-domain).

Comment: Thank you for the link, this is exactly what I have done. I added and answer to my post.